# WIX: does VS2013_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED property works?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, visual-studio-2013, wix3.8

My installer must show warning when no Web Developer component of Visual Studio installed.
Here is the code:

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Show Dialog="VWDDlg" After="CostFinalize" >
      <![CDATA[NOT (Installed OR VS2010_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED OR VS2012_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED OR VS2013_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED)]]>
    </Show>
  </InstallUISequence>
```

It works for VS2010 (shows when the component is not installed and doesn't show after installing it), but not shown for VS2012 and VS2013 when they installed without "Microsoft Web Developer Tools".

[image: Picture]

Maybe VS2013_IDE_VWD_PROJECTSYSTEM_INSTALLED is not connected with "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" component?